# Why is this rational expressions indeterminate when evaluated?

Tags: rational-functions, indeterminate-forms

I have this rational expression to evaluate,
$$
{{3a-3}\over {4a(a-1)}} \text { if } a=1.
$$

I understand that if you substitute 1, both the numerator and denominator would turn out 0, thus  making it indeterminate. But what if I factor out the numerator $3a-3$ to $3(a-1)$ and cancel out $(a-1)$ from both the numerator and denominator, wouldn't it just give $3\over4$ as the answer?

Comment: 'Cancelling out $(a - 1)$' is exactly the same as dividing by $(a - 1)$. You can only divide by a non-zero number, in particular, you can't do it if $a = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this function:

$$\frac{3a-3}{4a(a-1)}$$

When $a=1$ this function will not be defined at that specific x-value.

The reason is because:

$$\frac{3a-3}{4a(a-1)} = \frac{3}{4a}$$

Even though the $(a-1)$ term cancels, the function still isn't defined at that point. We call $a = 1$ to be a **hole** in the function.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/grphrtnl4.htm)

Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: More precisely, the point $\,a=1\,$ is a [removable singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities), sometimes also called a removable discontinuity.

Comment: @BillDubuque yes you area also correct. I prefer to call it hole, but removable discontinuity is the correct term to describe this point.

Comment: Actually that latter term is a bit of an abuse of terminology, as the Wikipedia article explains. The former term is more precise.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you so much @VarunIyer!